# How to put value in JSONObject without quotations

Tags: javascript, java, json, alpacajs

I am working on a project using Alpacajs forms, creating schema JSON on java, now I need to make a json which have value with not double quotations like:

```
        "buttons": {
            "submit": {
                "click": function() {
                    this.refreshValidationState(true);
                    if (!this.isValid(true)) {
                        this.focus();
                        return;
                    }
                    this.ajaxSubmit();
                }
            }
        }
```

here is my code:

```
JSONObject ob = new JSONObject();
JSONObject button = new JSONObject();
JSONObject submit = new JSONObject();
        submit.put("click", "function() {"
                  +"this.refreshValidationState(true);"
                  +"if (!this.isValid(true)) {"
                  +"     this.focus();"
                  +"    return;"
                  +"}"
                  +"this.ajaxSubmit();"
                  +"}");
button.put("submit", submit);
ob.put("buttons", button);
```

but I'm getting this:
after calling toJSONString();

```
"buttons": {
  "submit": {
    "click": "function() {this.refreshValidationState(true);if (!this.isValid(true)) {     this.focus();    return;}this.ajaxSubmit();}"
  }
```

The value of click is in double quotes but I need it without quotes, how can I remove that double quotes from JSONObject using toJSONString() method.
any Idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Please define "_javascript is not working on it_". In JSON, property names must be wrapped in quotes, and JS should work fine. Passing a function within a JSON string is probably your actual issue?

Comment: JS Objects can contain functions. But JSON strings cannot contain functions.

Comment: here is the link http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/api/forms.html from where I am getting example creating form. if i am putting it as it is working fine but it is not working if the json value has double quotes.

Comment: That's not JSON on that page. That is full-blown **Javascript**. JSON is a very limited subset of Javascript that does not allow you to define functions.

Comment: I'm not defining function but I need such kind of JSON because this formate is used in Alpacajs to create actions on forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked on it and go through the source code of JSONObject, got an Idea and solve the problem.

JSONObject is adding quotations on String but not on Object, so I made a class,

```
public class Method implements java.io.Serializable{

    /** use serialVersionUID for interoperability */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String value;

    public Method(String value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

And made the object of that class like this:

```
        JSONObject submit = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject button = new JSONObject();
        String value = "function() {"
                +"this.refreshValidationState(true);"
                +"if (!this.isValid(true)) {"
                +"     this.focus();"
                +"    return;"
                +"}"
                +"this.ajaxSubmit();"
                +"}";
        Method click =new Method(value);
        submit.put("click", click);
        button.put("submit", submit);
        button.toJSONString();
```

Now the problem is solved and code is working fine, and the output is as I need.

```
    "buttons": {
        "submit": {
            "click": function() {
                this.refreshValidationState(true);
                if (!this.isValid(true)) {
                    this.focus();
                    return;
                }
                this.ajaxSubmit();
            }
        }
    }
```